# Prevent sticky keys programmatically

Tags: angular

Our requirement is, I have to prevent sticky key dialogue box in our Angular 5 web application when we press shift key 5 times. How do I proceed?

Comment: You can't, the browser has no control over that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: can we do through windows registry?any suggestion.